# Passing optional param in http request builder

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

I am new to scala and Gatling and need help with the below case:
I have an API request which has an optional parameter which may or may not have a value based on the application workflow.
my HTTP request builder is designed ->

```
`getTestRequest(param1, param2, param3)
return http(getTestRequest)
.queryParam("param1","value1")
.queryParam("param2","value2")
.queryParam("param3","value3")`
```

I want to pass/not pass param1 in this request based on the value of param3, what is the way to go about this scenario?

I tried queryParamMaps and doIfEquals but they don't work in the http request builder

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do something like this:

```java
doIfEqualsOrElse("#{param3}", someValue).then(
  exec(requestWithParam1)
).orElse(
  exec(requestWithoutParam1)
)
```